# How to create as many variables as needed from shell script(bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, user-input

I'm making a script for monitoring some user processes with Upstart but, since its for the company I work for, they asked me to do it generic...how's so?
Well, the number of processes being monitored could vary, as in number as in name so I need to create it so a user can input "n" number of processes and give the shell its pathname's so I can store them in variables and pass Upstart a script with them so my question is: how can I create as many variables as needed?

Here's my script so far…

`./script input`

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1
i=1

while read LINE
do
[rutaServ$i]=$LINE
echo "ruta -> [rutaServ$i]"
i=`expr $i + 1`
done < $FILENAME
```

As you can see I am taking the pathname provisionally from a plain text file with nothing more than `/home/user` lines in it but, when I run this script I get the following error `[rutaServ1]=/home/user: The file or directory doesn't exists`

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your array syntax is off just a bit. Also, there's no need for the index variable; you can use the `+=` operator to append to an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1

rutaServ=()
while read LINE
do
rutaserv+=($LINE)
echo "ruta -> $LINE"
done < "$FILENAME"
```

`bash` v4 has a new command, `mapfile` (or `readarray`) to read the contents of a file into an array all at once:

```
mapfile rutaServ < "$FILENAME"
```

To access values from the array:

```
for x in "${rutaserv[@]}"; do
    echo "$x"
done
```

Comment: Ok, tried this and worked but after the loop if I try something like `echo $LINE` I get nothing in the output.
How can I access the values of the array?

Comment: great! that worked! Now I have a doubt, what does the "@" stands for in the index array?

Comment: Think of it as "a for all": it expands the array to a list of words, one word per element in the array. It is quoted so that any element that contains whitespace will be treated as a single word.

Answer (score 1):

Could the script be called like `script.sh process1 process2`? Then you could refer to the arguments with `$@`:

```
# set process1 process2 # set arguments for testing

for x in "$@"; do 
    echo "ruta -> $x"
done
```

`[rutaServ$i]=$LINE` should be `rutaServ[$i]=$LINE` or `rutaServ+=("$LINE")`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion for the index before I try the arguments option because, I don't know how many processes will be, it could take long to write all arguments. So...here's my new code where in the end I test the variables...

`while read LINE
do` 
`rutaServ[$i]=$LINE
echo "ruta -> $rutaServ$i"
done < "$FILENAME"`

`i=1
while [ $i -le 3  ]
do
echo $rutaServ$i
i=`expr $i + 1`
done`
Now it works as saving the variables but when printing, it appends a number to the path:
`/home/user/ruta31`
`/home/user/ruta32`
`/home/user/ruta33`

Comment: You can access array elements like `echo "${rutaServ[$i]}"`.